# transpose in SQL

Tags: sql, transpose

Can I transpose results in `SQL` just like I have it in excel. No hard coded values as I have different results every time.

For example, I have a table of employees and I want it to just convert rows into columns and columns into rows.

Thank you.

Comment: Look into `PIVOT`. Also, which database are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: pivot works with wither group by or sum() or min() i want a simple table to transpose

Comment: The link you posted had hard coded values, it's mentioned that hard coded values wont work, I want all tables I selected to shift rows to columns

Comment: the link has dynamic sql utilized to pivot, it is not hard coded values.  Additionally on the answer linked there is a stored procedure that will seemingly pivot data for you.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: i cannot use dynamic values i am not sure about the table's data in the future.